# Can I reinstall or reset Calendar? Delegates disappearing and reappearing

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, caldav

A colleague is having an issue with CalDAV where delegations keep appearing and reappearing. They dont stay on the calendar and every refresh of Delegates leads different results.

The Calendar works fine for everyone else and only happened to the one user during an upgrade. I tried with a different email on that machine and it works fine so am stumped to what is causing this.

Is there a way to reset the Calendar app?

Answer (score 5):

Try and remove all content in ~/Library/calendars. **Warning** this does remove all calendars that are only on the local machine.

Also try and remove `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist` **Warning** this removes all settings of Calendar.app.

Otherwise try and reinstall OSX, See: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14193